# F13 is incorrectly treated as numpad Enter in vcxsrv

Tags: keyboard, remapping, vcxsrv

I use SharpKeys on my Windows 8 machine to rebind the Caps Lock key to F13 so that I can use it as a hotkey/modifier in other programs. This works fine in Windows applications--for example, http://keycode.info/ correctly reports that I've hit F13 when I press Caps Lock.

However, this does not seem to work in vcxsrv, which treats the key as `KP_Enter`, i.e. Enter on the numpad. The output from `xev` is identical regardless of whether I press Caps Lock or the real numpad Enter key. This behavior is not affected by Num Lock, the `-keyhook` argument to vcxsrv, or the `-xkbvariant nodeadkeys` argument to vcxsrv, which is everything I could think to try myself. As far as I can tell this is the only key that is not passed through correctly.

In case it matters, I'm using PuTTY to SSH into a Fedora 28 VM to run the X applications I'm using (like `xev`).

Comment: Fails the same in x2go, which uses vcxsrv.  (And I have F13-F18, they all have similar issues.)